# How to keep socket.io connection alive during image selection on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios, websocket, socket.io

my website is creating a WebSocket connection via socket.io to any device connecting to create a real-time chat. Clients can also upload an image to the chat by clicking a button and selecting an image on their computer.

This works fine on most devices - except iOS devices. These devices seam to disconnect their WebSocket connection when a user is searching their photo library for more than a few seconds.

Is there any fix to this, keeping the WebSocket connection alive?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I have found, but it does make sense - when the tab is out of focus / closed the JS should stop executing so the socket dies.

You could try getting the image from an element in the page showing the camera so that the page is 'in focus'? Once you're back on the page, presumably it reconnects, so what are the events you need to respond to when the focus is on the camera instead of the page? Can these be addressed through push notifications or another way?

Comment: I have now resolved this error the following way:

The client will save its previous socket ID (given by socket.io). When it notices, that it is reconnecting, it will send its old socket ID and new socket ID to the server which then updates the socket ID used for sending messages.